# Gmail mobile website messed up in default internet browser

Tags: 2.2-froyo, gmail, internet, samsung-galaxy-ace, stock-browser

For a few weeks now the Gmail mobile site is messed up in default internet browser. The scroll doesn't work properly and when you "touch" things it doesn't work "visually" although it quite works. For example, if I click the 4th inbox message, it looks like it clicked the 2nd message instead of the 4th. It's confusing to use. Another example is when I click the Search icon, it disappears when I try to type something.

I tried clearing cache, clear data from Manage applications, hard reboot several times, but it doesn't appear to get fixed. Anyone knows to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the pre-installed app that was installed in your system.
The gmail shown in your Android device is much more different than the one on PC.
I suggest using/updating the GMail APP better than the browser :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the website seems to be very heavy for your smartphone's default web Browser, Why don't you use other third party browsers?
you may try [Dolphin Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser) or [UC Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.UCMobile.intl&hl=en) they works fine.

Comment: I have been using it for more than a year and it only happened now. BTW Dolphin Browser uses the default browser.